# How to insert a sub value within an element without affecting the main text of the element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to insert this number 4 into my own tile.
[image]

The image below is my elements code. I have tried using the subscript element but the numbers would interfere with my letter H. Such as resulting in my element to output H4 instead of H alone. I use `textContent` to access the letter of the tile element.

JavaScript:

```
function makeLetters() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i += 1) {
        const makeTile = document.createElement("div");
        ++count;
        makeTile.id = `letter-tile${count}`;
        makeTile.className = "letter-tile";
        makeTile.draggable = true;
        const node = document.createTextNode(`${newPlayerLetters[count]}`);

        const sub = document.createElement("sub");
        const subNode = document.createTextNode("4");
        sub.append(subNode);

        makeTile.appendChild(node);
        makeTile.append(sub);

        const elemDiv = document.getElementById(`player-rack${i}`);
        elemDiv.appendChild(makeTile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to make just the bottom text as an index without breaking the position of the main text? And insert pls your html code with text and not with a picture.

Comment: And another question .. Is the subscript inserted dynamically?

Comment: makeLetters() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i += 1) {
    const makeTile = document.createElement('div');
    ++count;
    makeTile.id = `letter-tile${count}`;
    makeTile.className = 'letter-tile';
    makeTile.draggable = true;
    const node = document.createTextNode(`${newPlayerLetters[count]}`);
    const sub = document.createElement("sub");
    const subNode = document.createTextNode("4");
    sub.append(subNode);
    makeTile.appendChild(node);
    makeTile.append(sub)
    const elemDiv = document.getElementById(`player-rack${i}`);
    elemDiv.appendChild(makeTile);
  }
}

Comment: Oh god, the indentation. Sorry. How could I make the subscript dynamic?